# Tool to bulk remove Facebook status updates

Tags: facebook, privacy

Is there any tool/webapp out there that will let me bulk delete past status updates?

The only solution I have found so far is going back manually and deleting them one by one.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a program called iMacros that allows you to automate any browser based task, such as deleting status updates. Here's one I found to delete your facebook statuses: http://www.cynthiaperla.com/facebook/460/how-to-delete-all-groups-and-wall-posts-from-facebook-using-imacros.html

Comment: Great tip! If all else fails atleast I can clean it all out. Im looking for some more detailed control over what to remove though but this is by far better information then I got from googling for an hour before asking the question :)

Comment: Seems like this solution is outdated now. Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

There is the userscript [Absterge](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/122073)

> Absterge works such that a user logs in to the Facebook Timeline, and navigates to the 'Activity Log' section. The removal process automatically unrolls all user's activity (by triggering click to "More Activity" link), and then removes every activity that can be removed from the logs. The only required user's activity so far is to expand the year where the logs are chronologically classified. The script deletes everything.
>
> 1. Install Firefox (any OS on any architecture)
> 2. Install Greasemonkey (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/...)
> 3. Download and install the Absterge script available above.
> 4. Log in to Facebook and make sure that Facebook Timeline is available.
> 5. Navigate to the ‘Activity Log’.
> 6. The script will start unrolling the current expanded year triggering the ‘More Activity’ click event.
> 7. As soon as the script finds posts / comments / status updates, those will be automatically removed, without warnings.
> 8. In order to remove the activity of another year, just expand the year tab. The script will take care of the rest.

Comment: Why? What makes this userscript so suitable to the task?

Answer (score 0):

There is a python script that is open source that will do much of this for you - at the very least it can remove old statuses and pictures.

https://github.com/chander/social-network-cleaner