# Script or App to remove own Facebook status updates

Tags: facebook, greasemonkey

I am totally aware of [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/tool-to-bulk-remove-facebook-status-updates), however this isn't a very elegant solution that seems very buggy or even outdated, judging from the comments.

I heard that there was a Greasemonkey/UserScript that would achieve the same goal: Removing all my own status updates from the Facebook profile (but for example not what other people have posted me). I could not find it - has anybody got an idea?

In other terms - would it be possible for me to write my own Facebook app that achieves that goal, i.e. by using the Facebook API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an app like Exfoliate, available on Android phones, that can
delete everything you’ve posted on friends’ walls, including comments
and likes, as well as your own wall. It cleans out photo galleries too.
You can set the age of stuff you want deleted too. Search for Exfoliate
in the Android Marketplace to find it, or:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.worb.android.exfoliate

Comment: Looks helpful indeed. What methods does it use, actually?

Comment: It doesn't look like that app is available any more.

Answer (score 5):

You would be able to write your own Facebook App to do this as you can use the following APIs:

- https://graph.facebook.com/%yourusername%

  - This will return your profile details including your UID
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/status.get

  - This returns all of your status updates by passing your UID
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.remove

  - You pass your UID & Status_ID to this API to remove a post.  The Post_ID is a combination of your UID & Status_Id in the format of `UID_StatusID` along with your UID.

If you create an application you would have to allow the application to access your wall etc.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot - this is helpful. I will see how easy it is to implement.